# Pls, How can I expand my ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning

I wish to expand my Ubuntu 12.04 Partition. Pls help?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the geniuses at Ubuntu, it's actually quite easy. **Please Note, that it may destroy data, so backup everything before attempting**:

1) Boot from a Live CD / USB

2) Open `GParted`

3) Select `Resize / Move`

4) Move Partitions After Your Partition, and Resize The Partition

5) Reboot

Thats it, you're done. If anything is screwed up, just use your backup that I know you made.